# listbox with radio button and checkbox both in one

Tags: c#, listbox

i need a list box which has check box for first 4 items and radio button for next 4 items.... these items are driven from database.... where i can select any number of item from check box and only one from radio button. how to add them dynamically from database to list box

```
 listBox1.Items.Add("Sunday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Monday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Wednesday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Thursday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Friday"); 
listBox1.Items.Add("Saturday");
```

Comment: What does the code you have included have to do with your question? Note: You can probably just use [DayOfWeek enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of writing them yourself

Comment: Why would you combin checkboxes and radiobuttons in a list control? That seems to violate the way those kind of items a generally handled. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want first four days to be checkbox item and then next three to be radiobutton

Comment: the requirement is like so brother

Comment: This has nothing to do with a ListBox! You need a UserControl (or possibly a FlowLayoutPanel or even a TableLayoutPanel)  with methods to read/write from/to your DBMS. Create the UC and the rest will happen by itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go by like this:

**Xaml:**

```
        <ListBox Name="uiList" Width="300" Height="600"/>
```

**Code:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Length; i++)
        {
            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

            if (i < 4)
            {
                panel.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
            }
            else
            {
                panel.Children.Add(new RadioButton() { GroupName = "SameGRoupName" });
            }
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = ((DayOfWeek)i).ToString() });
            uiList.Items.Add(panel);
        }
```

**Result:**

[image]

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vak6302ww08u76h/StackQuestion.zip?dl=0)

Comment: i dint get ur code...can u plz explain me properly. ThankQ

Comment: @pramodniralakeri Did you copied this code to your solution?

Comment: @pramodniralakeri take a look at demo project https://www.dropbox.com/s/vak6302ww08u76h/StackQuestion.zip?dl=0

Comment: ThankQ so much brother... Brother i need some favor from you... can we contact personally through mail? i badly need your mind for my project

Comment: If I can, I will help you, see my Profile @pramodniralakeri

Comment: how to know a dynamically created checkbox is checked or not? it consist of postback and viewstate which retain the control values

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < int.Parse(txt_sem.Text); x++)
        {
            var chk = new CheckBox { ID = "chk_"+x.ToString()};
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
//do something            }
            else
            {
//do something
            }
        }

Comment: @pramodniralakeri  You can go by  if (chk.IsChecked == true)
            {
                //here checked
            }
            else
            {
                //do when unchecked 
            }

Comment: how to mark? its saying need 15 reputation when i click upward direction arrow

Comment: brother had sent u mail which u given in ur profile...please check it n let me know